# how the packuswb instruction works ? (in low level bit operation)

Tags: assembly, ffmpeg, x86-64, sse

Studying ffmpeg convertion from yuv to rgb , I came across the equation being implemented in assembly, yuv2rgb_template.c located in ffmpeg/libswscale/x86.

I want to know how the instruction packuswb works ? Google says it :

Converts 4 signed word integers from mm and 4 signed word integers from mm/m64 into 8 unsigned byte integers in mm using unsigned saturation.

```
    DEST[7:0] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte DEST[15:0];
    DEST[15:8] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte DEST[31:16];
    DEST[23:16] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte DEST[47:32];
    DEST[31:24] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte DEST[63:48];
    DEST[39:32] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte SRC[15:0];
    DEST[47:40] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte SRC[31:16];
    DEST[55:48] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte SRC[47:32];
    DEST[63:56] ← SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte SRC[63:48];
```

Since I dont know Assembly x86, it is even hard to simulate it or debug the current code.

I want to know how they fit 16 bits in 8 bits ?

Comment: You're just looking at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packuswb or something.  That's an HTML extract from the full Intel vol.2 manual, which has a section that defines most of those "function" names they use for their pseudocode.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-2a-2b-2c-and-2d-instruction-set-reference-a-z / https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SaturateSignedWordToUnsignedByte` means to clip to 8-bit range. So >=0x100 becomes 0xFF, <=-1 becomes 0, and the rest (0-0xFF) is unmodified.